# How to show the items on a list using foreach outside the method where the list is in (C#)

Tags: c#, list, methods, foreach

So, I'm creating a program in C# that will read Income and Outgo, both provided by the user, and will store them in 2 lists. When requested, the program must show the values stored inside the lists. The problem is, the list is located in an method, and the foreach used to show the values is in another method, and every time I try to call the name of the list, the compiler says to me: "The name does not exist in the current context". Any help will be welcome.

This is the method to create the list:

```
public void ListIncome()
{
    Console.Clear();
    Console.Write("Income: ");
    List<double> Income = new List<double>();
    Income.Add(Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine()));
}
```

And this is the method to show the list:

```
public void ShowList()
{
    foreach (double value in Income)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: You are creating the List inside your `ListIncome()` method, as soon as that method adds the user input to the List it is immediately flagged for garbage collection (meaning it will be destroyed).  Your list should be a class member (ideally a property).  That way, _all_ methods can access it.  I would recommend taking an intro to C# course, I think you could benefit from an overview of the fundamentals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your `Income` variable is not in `ListIncome` method scope so, you need to move it to class level scope to be accessible to other member methods.

You need to create the list a field so that it can be accessible outside the method too where you are populating it:

```
public class YourClass
{

   List<double> Income = new List<double>(); // field added

   public void ListIncome()
   {
      Console.Clear();
      Console.Write("Income: ");
      Income.Add(Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine()));
   }

  public void ShowList()
  {
     foreach (double value in Income)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(value);
     }
     Console.ReadKey();
  }

}
```

and now it should be accessible in those methods, and your methods will also be in the same class for this case to work like above.

Answer (score 1):

You can not call a variable encapsulated in a method from another method, therefore, you must declare it at the class level, so that all methods of it can access said variable

```
private List<double> Income = new List<double>();

public void ListIncome()
{
    Console.Clear();
    Console.Write("Income: ");
    Income.Add(Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine()));
}

public void ShowList()
{
    foreach (double value in Income)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

So you understand better

`A` is a local variable. It can not be accessed from another method, only inside `method()`

```
public void method()
{
   int A = 0;
}
```

`A` is now a class level  variable, All methods of the class can access this because it is declared in the class and not encapsulated (limited to the method) inside a method

```
public class SomeClass
{
    int A = 0; 

    public method()
    {
        int X = A / 5;  
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your answer would be much stronger if you spent some more time explaining why your answer solves the OPs problem

Comment: Also explain why global variables are the solution over class properties or fields.

Comment: What is "report it by class" and how does that relate to "it creates global variables"?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "global variable" in C#. What would the context of "global" mean, anyway? Global would surely mean "all across the program", or? Since you answered a beginner in C#, you should pay attention to the nomenclature you use and whether it helps understanding or seeds misunderstandings/confusion...

Comment: That's not a "global variable", that's a private class field.